# Change email address that sends confirmation email (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, html, email

I have a registration page on a site I'm working on.  When the person registers for an account it sends an email to the registrants email address with a confirmation link to activate the persons account. The problem is that the "from" email address the registrant receives the email from is: `myhostingaccountusername@myhostingprovider###.com`.

I want to be able to have the email be: `no-reply@mydomain.com`.

I'm using PHP and Mysql along with html for the site.

here is my code for sending the email.

```
// Send the email:
    $body = "Thank you for registering at My site. To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
    $body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x=' . urlencode($e) . "&y=$abc";
    mail($trimmed['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: noreply@mysite.com');
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using PhpMailer to send emails or some other library?

Comment: How can we know? We don't even know what system you're using to send the emails, you didn't show any code.

Comment: Sorry about that! I knew i was missing something. I added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending the e-mail to your "registrant" you should set the headers of the mail function in PHP to contain "From" field

for example :

```
 <?php
 $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
 $subject = 'the subject';
 $message = 'hello';
 $headers = 'From: no-reply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: me@example.com' . "\r\n";

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

Comment: The mail is sent but just from one mail ??!! that is, it does not accept to send when you put your "no-reply@yourdomain.com" email??

Comment: Now what's happening is I get the from address, but now I get the hosting and server name as the "sent via" info in gmail. Does that make sense? Another question is this: if the email does not exist on the server for that domain (like i'm using a test domain) will that cause issues? Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: I think that has something to do with your problem if the email is not on the domain I think it does not work I have tried something like that sometime ago :))

Comment: I'll add the email tot he test domain and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `From:` header for the e-mail?

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, example #2.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Yes, as i posted the code above, the header is set, but it does not show up that way in the email.